# Livestreamer - scheduling recording with Debian Linux variant distros

Tags: video-streaming, cron, live-streaming, video-recording

I am using livestreamer to record periodic live streamed video from  youtube as follows

```
livestreamer <youtube-live-url> best -o out_file.mp4
```

A recording needs to be made every 8pm to 10pm each Thursday.

I cannot always be at the computer at these times.

I was thinking to use `crontab-e` to start the recording with the above command at the given time, 8pm Thursday's, which is easy enough.

The stream has to be stopped with CTRL+C at 10pm the same day.
Killing the process will not work as the stream will not then be written out to file. The live stream must be closed off with CTRL+C.

The problem is I don't know how to assign a PID to the initial process then send CTRL+C to the same process, all done from crontab, to close the stream and write the file out.

Anyone any ideas. Perhaps Crontab is, or is not, the best way to persue this problem.

A specific working recipe, to effect this recording, if anyone has one, pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [timeout](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html).  It allows you to run a command and terminate it with a specific kill signal after a given amount of time.

You could use this in your cron command to stop livestreamer with ctrl-c (SIGINT) after 2 hours.

You should use full paths for timeout and livestreamer in your cron commands.  You can find these with *which*:

```
$ which timeout
/usr/bin/timeout

$ which livestreamer
/usr/local/bin/livestreamer
```

To record a two-hour segment your cron command would be:

```
/usr/bin/timeout -s SIGINT 2h /usr/local/bin/livestreamer <url> /path/to/out.mp4
```

Comment: hi @Z0n3r For a short test I used `12 23 * * * timeout -s SIGINT 1m livestreamer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y60wDzZt8yg 240p -o live8.mp4`. It does not work. I think because crontab releases the process after it gets going and it can't identify the right one to close it off with SIGINT. Any ideas? (ps from the terminal, outside crontab, `timeout -s SIGINT 1m livestreamer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y60wDzZt8yg 240p -o live8.mp4` works just great)

Comment: @Kes try adding full paths for both timeout and livestreamer in your cron command.  Use 'which timeout' and 'which livestreamer' to verify these and change your cron command to eg:  /usr/bin/timeout -s SIGINT 1m /usr/local/bin/livestreamer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y60wDzZt8yg 240p -o live8.mp4

Comment: Here is what worked. It's what you have with the addition of the outfile location; `23 0 * * * /usr/bin/timeout -s SIGINT 1m /usr/local/bin/livestreamer youtube.com/watch?v=y60wDzZt8yg 240p -o /home/kes/Desktop/out_file.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

may be add --yes-run-as-root

CODE: 
23 0 * * * /usr/bin/timeout -s SIGINT 1m /usr/local/bin/livestreamer youtube.com/watch?v=y60wDzZt8yg 240p -o /home/kes/Desktop/out_file.mp4 --yes-run-as-root